# Why can I not save these items to an array in jquery

Tags: jquery

I think there's a scope issue in the code below, but I'm trying to save the values returned by the geocode callback function to the polyline array, but when I run console.log, the array is empty.

```
var addPolyline = function(map, line) {

        var polyline = [];

        $.each(line, function(index, address){

            geocode(address, function(latlng){
                polyline.push(latlng);
                console.log(polyline);
            });

        });

        console.log(polyline);
    }
```

Can someone please tell me how I can add the elements from the callback function to the array? Thanks

**Edit:** The points are being added to the polyline array, but the console.log(polyline) is being executed before $.each finishes. I need to figure out a way to wait until it's finished.

**Edit2:** One responder said to use callbacks. I tried this with the following code, but callback(polyline) is still being executed before $.each is finished.

```
    var addPolyline = function(map, line) {

        formatPolyline(line, function(polyline){
            console.log(polyline);
        });
    }

    var formatPolyline = function(line, callback) {

        var polyline = [];

        $.each(line, function(index, address){

            geocode(address, function(latlng){
                polyline.push(latlng);
                console.log(polyline);
            });

        });

        callback(polyline);
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried to debug if the polyline.push is even executed? debug line element? Also read the each documentation (I assume you are using jquery) http://api.jquery.com/each/

Comment: put `console.log(polyline)` inside the loop and you could see the data one by one.

Comment: What is `geocode`?  It's probably asynchronous.  Meaning the `$.each` finishes and your `console.log` is ran *before* `geocode`'s callback is ran.

Comment: Or maybe geocode is not even executed, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5782611/how-do-i-use-google-maps-geocoder-getlatlng-and-store-its-result-in-a-database Here is a little bit of how to use it

Comment: geocode is definitely being executed, because I can see the coordinates. the problem is, the coordinates aren't added until after the callback is called, or after the $.each is finished, depending on which example you are looking at above

Comment: Your `callback` solution is still the same issue.  You need to use `geocode`'s callbacks!  That's where the asynchronous code is.  If we can see the code for the `geocode` function, we can help more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

geocode is 'nonblocking' or 'asynchronous' which means that the program will continue to execute before geocode has finished. That is why `console.log(polyline)` logs an empty array.

The solution is to use callbacks.

The code below uses a counter which increments on every geocode callback. At the last geocode call; the function myCallback is called, in which you can put whatever code you like.

```
var addPolyline = function(map, line) {

    var polyline = [],
        total = $(line).length,
        count = 0,
        myCallback = function(){
            console.log(polyline);
        };

    $.each(line, function(index, address){
        geocode(address, function(latlng){
            polyline.push(latlng);
            count++;
            if(count === total){
                myCallback();
            }
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: I updated my answer by using the callback approach, and it's still not working. could you please give an example?